# Relativelayout circual dependancy

Tags: java, android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create my android app for a lot of different devices so I'm trying to avoid using fixed heights and width and instead using the property WRAP_CONTENT.

Now I need to create a textview on top of a button and align that to the bottom. However the documentation states that you can't use WRAP_CONTENT in combination with ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM (which is obvious). Is there another way to achieve this?

The structure is something like this. A RelativeLayout which wraps a button and a textview.

```
RelativeLayout fl = new RelativeLayout(this);
fl.setLayoutParams(relativeWrapContentParams);
fl.addView(filterBtn);
fl.addView(filterCaption);
```

The buttons are also created dynamically so theres no xml. Instead the buttons are created in java code.

Also is this a good way of programming for multiple resolutions? Or is it ok to use fixed heights because then the problem is easy to fix and I can just give the relativelayout a fixed height and align its children with ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM

Comment: why do you think that layouts are not good as compare to dynamic view? what you are thinking is not true.

Comment: i dont really get what you're trying to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) this article is the bible for the newbies in android.

Now coming to your question you don't need to use relative layout just for this purpose
you can use linearlayout with vertical orientation place text and then button.

and you need to place this linearlayout inside relative layout with property alignparentbottom=true.

in such way you can have this layout of text and button at the bottom of the screen